# Microsoft OAuth2 return error=access_denied

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying using OAuth2 on my MVC 5 web app but I'm getting trouble with OAuth2 from Microsoft. When I signed on using Microsoft it returned error=access_denied. Below are my configurations:

1. Set up public key, secret key and password http://apps.dev.microsoft.com/ . (You must create key pair and password)
2. Set up return Url https://localhost:44300/sign-microsoft
3. Add these key pair which are application Id and secret key to Startup.Auth.cs

> ```
> app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(
> new MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationOptions()
> {
>   ClientId = "xxxx",
>   ClientSecret = "xxx",
>   Scope = { "wl.basic", "wl.emails" }
> });
> ```

4. Below is action

> ```
> [HttpPost]
> [AllowAnonymous]
> [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
> public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
> {
>   if (provider.Equals("Microsoft"))
>       returnUrl = "https://localhost:44300/signin-microsoft";
>   // Request a redirect to the external login provider
>   return new ChallengeResult(provider, Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { ReturnUrl =
> ```
>
> returnUrl }));
>       }

I've looked around someone got trouble and solved by using https. I have spent several days but I can't find out the problem.

Comment: Any luck? I am having the same issue.

Comment: Using localhost works with most providers, but currently does not work with the Microsoft provider. For the Microsoft provider, you must include a valid web site URL. Or create an dummy domain in your lmhosts file (fe: mywebsite.local)